# How can one construct a densest graph with no k-clique?

Tags: ds.algorithms, graph-theory, co.combinatorics

> Given integers $k$ and $n$ with $2 \le k < n$,
>   how does one construct a graph on $n$ vertices
>   that contains no $k$-clique and has the maximal
>   number of edges?

This sounds like basic combinatorics, but I don't know where to find the result.  Pointers would be welcome if this is well-known.

Ideally I would like a deterministic procedure to construct such a maximal graph in $n^{O(1)}$ time.

One graph with $n$ vertices that is guaranteed not to contain $K_k$ is $\overline{K_{n-k+2} + \overline{K_{k-2}}}$, the complement of the graph formed by the disjoint union of $K_{n-k+2}$ and $k-2$ isolated vertices.  Whenever one picks $k$ vertices from it, at least two of these must be from the subset which is completely disconnected, so they cannot form a clique.  This can clearly be constructed in polynomial time, and is quite dense for $k$ close to $n$.  However, this construction yields rather sparse graphs when $k$ is small relative to $n$, so it seems unlikely to be the optimal construction.

Comment: I actually needed this to ask another question: http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/1441/hardness-of-parameterized-clique

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Turan's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turan%27s_theorem) exactly characterizes the densest graphs on n vertices with no k clique. [The Turan graphs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tur%C3%A1n_graph) are the maximal graphs, and they're very easy to construct. Is this what you want?