# Sparse graphs versus dense graphs

Tags: ds.algorithms, graph-theory, graph-algorithms

I am curious if there are graphs problems for which either -

1. we know that time and/or space complexity is independent of graph sparsity
2. we do not know whether or not graph sparsity can be exploited to reduce time and/or space complexity

Among many possible notions of the sparsity, I am particularly interested in the one that relies on edge density (or alternatively, average degree).

Comment: Suppose the problem takes time O(m+n) to solve ? is that considered "independent of the sparsity" ?

Comment: @SureshVenkat - I'd say that is not independent of the sparsity -- time complexity improves as the graph gets sparser.

Comment: Here is one example - storing all pairs shortest distances is believed to, I think, require $\Omega(n^2)$ space. If this is right, that would be one example.

Comment: I see so one thing you might be looking for is a problem where lower bounds depend only on $n$ ?

Comment: Yes, problems for which lower and upper bounds are independent of $m$ would be interesting.

Comment: for example Johnson's algorithm for all pairs shortest path is $O(V^2 \log V + VE)$ and for sparse graphs e.g when $|E| = O(V)$ it will be $O(V^2 \log V)$, It's not independent from $E$ in general but it's extremely faster than normal ford-falkerson in sparse graphs.

Comment: I don't understand.  If we know that the time complexity is independent of sparsity, then _by definition_ we know that sparsity cannot be exploited to reduce the time complexity.  What am I missing?

Comment: @Jeff - I am looking for problems for which either 1 holds or 2 holds.

Comment: There are NP-complete problems that remain NPC even for cubic graphs. Does this count as an example for 1?

Comment: it depends how you define "sparse". if its a small constant fraction then one answer is in this question [hardness of parameterized clique](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/1441/hardness-of-parameterized-clique). also, equivalently, monotone circuit theory states that many NP complete problems (incl SAT, clique detection) have NP complete "slices" which are inputs with the same number of 1's. also relevant, [mahaney's thm](http://blog.computationalcomplexity.org/2007/06/sparse-sets-tribute-to-mahaney.html) that says there are no NP complete sparse sets unless P==NP